# Error android Studio Firebase leer datos

Tags: java, android-studio

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Post post = mPosts.get(position);

            holder.username.setText(this.username);

            if(imgURL.equals("default"))
                holder.img_perfil.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_person_red);
            else
                Glide.with(mContext).load(imgURL).into(holder.img_perfil);


            holder.mensaje.setText(post.getMessage());


            if(post.getEstado_animo().equals("Normal"))
                holder.animo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cara_normal);
            else if(post.getEstado_animo().equals("Triste"))
                holder.animo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cara_triste);
            else if(post.getEstado_animo().equals("Feliz"))
                holder.animo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cara_feliz);

    }
```

Esa lista de Post viene de este metodo

```
private void leerPost(){
        mPosts = new ArrayList<>();

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mPosts.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);


                            mPosts.add(post);


                    DatabaseReference reference2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(post.getSender());
                    reference2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                            postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), mPosts, user.getUsername(), user.getImageURL());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



    }
```

Lo que tengo es en una base de datos de FireBase un referencia "Post" donde hay valores "sender" "Mensaje" "Animo" cada ususario creado puede crear un post y lo que quiero es poder recolectar todos esos post y mostrar su mensaje etc pero me genera este error molesto que no se como arreglarlo, cree el PostAdapter para poder crear el RecyclerView dentro de un Fragment. Agradezco su ayuda.

Aqui el error "PID: 18504     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference"

Comment: El error es muy claro: Alguna de las cadenas sobre las que estás ejecutando la función `equals` tiene valor `null`. Cuál? No lo sé porque no has subido el error completo, que te diría la línea exacta. Revisa cómo obtienes esas cadenas porque algo está funcionando mal.

Comment: Tienes razon, cuando recupero el objeto List<Post> mPost y acceso a sus metodos getMessage etc me los da nulos, pero se supone que deberian ser los datos que recupere de Firebase, como soluciono eso? Se supone que los estoy recuperando en el segundo pedazo de codigo, no se si lo este haciendo mal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo pude solucionar parcialmente, el error que tenia era que mi clase Post tenia esta estructura:

´´´
public class Post {

```
private String sender;
private String menssage;
private String estado_animo;

public Post(String sender, String menssage, String estado_animo) {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.menssage = mensaje;
    this.estado_animo= animo;
}

public Post(){

}

public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(String sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}

public String getMensaje() {
    return menssage;
}

public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
    this.menssage= mensaje;
}

public String getAnimo() {
    return estado_animo;
}

public void setAnimo(String animo) {
    this.estado_animo= animo;
}
```

}

´´´

Y supongo qu epor alguna razon no reconocia los valores que tengo en mi Firebase debido a que tienen nombres diferentes es los atributos:

sender
mensaje
animo

Cambie los atributos de mi clase Post por estos mismos nombres y me funciono.